# Unicode-range CSS is working wrong in Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I used font-face to apply different fonts for each Japanese characters and English characters. It's working right in the gg chrome browser. But it seem did not working right in the Safari.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontFace';
  src: url('fonts/Normal/NormalN.ttf');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontFace';
  src: url('fonts/Normal/NormalB.ttf');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontFace';
  src: url('fonts/TimeFont/TimeN.otf');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  unicode-range: U+3000-9FFF, U+ff??;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontFace';
  src: url('fonts/TimeFont/timeB.otf');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  unicode-range: U+3000-9FFF, U+ff??;
}

* {
  font-family: 'FontFace', sans-serif;
}
```

It is always Normal font for every characters.

Comment: Please define "_not working right_".

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Could you create a simple runnable example, perhaps with just two commonly-available fonts and a line of text. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example